# How to append a table row towards last of a row with a specific class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to append a row to the html format of an asp data grid. My grid is having paging and that too is converted as a row in the html format. So, I added a class to the rows with the actual records. Now, i need to append an html table row to the grid. This should be appended towards the end of the records. Somebody knows how to do this?

Table Structure:

```
<table>
    <th>
    </th>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clientData">1</tr>
        <tr class="clientData">2</tr>
        <tr class="clientData">3</tr>
        <tr>Exclude This Row</tr>
        <tr>Exclude This Row</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script:

```
{ $("#ctl00_Content_GrdCustomer tbody").append(selCustomersRow); } //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$('#ctl00_Content_GrdCustomer tbody tr.clientData').last().after(selCustomersRow);
```

Or like Angel's comment, select directly the last tr.clientData :

```
$('#ctl00_Content_GrdCustomer tbody tr.clientData:last').after(selCustomersRow);
```

http://api.jquery.com/after/

Comment: This might be better: $('#ctl00_Content_GrdCustomer tbody tr.clientData:last').after(selCustomersRow);

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use the correct table tags.

i.e.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Column header 1</td>
            <td>Column header 2</td>
            <td>Column header 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Column footer 1</td>
            <td>Column footer 2</td>
            <td>Column footer 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

You may not need to have a header, but you can stick all of your "records" within the tbody and your pagination within the tfoot.

This way you can use

```
$("#ctl00_Content_GrdCustomer tbody").append(selCustomersRow);
```

Which will append the row to the end tbody, but before the pagination within the tfoot.

Comment: That's perfectly right, but I doubt that someone could tell asp how to render his data grid.

Comment: IIRC, the GridView control adds columns to the thead and pagination to the tfoot, leaving the actual data to exist in the tbody element.

Answer (score -1):

Try that ...

```
  { $("#ctl00_Content_GrdCustomer tbody tr").last().append(selCustomersRow); }
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, however the above code would append the row to the last TR, meaning nested TR's.

Comment: No... What your code does, is adds a TR within the last TR. This is invalid HTML code. What the OP needs, is to add the TR to the tbody but before the last TR. i.e. `{ selCustomersRow.before($("#ctl00_Content_GrdCustomer tbody tr").last()); }`